# For what values would accessing single bytes for XOR logic work faster than multiplication to find if two values have the same sign?

Tags: c, performance, x86, micro-optimization

For checking whether two numbers have the same sign:

```c
#define same_sign(a,b) ((a)*(b)>=0)
```

but this can also be done with:

```c
#define INTEL_REVERSED//example define specifying whether variables are stored in memory in reverse

#ifdef INTEL_REVERSED
    #define same_sign(a,b) ((~(*((char*)&a+sizeof(a)-1)^*((char*)&b+sizeof(b)-1))&0x80)>>7)
#else
    #define same_sign(a,b) ((~(*(char*)&a^*(char*)&b)&0x80)>>7)
#endif
```

Multiplication has time complexity of in between `O(n log n)` and `O(n^2)` (when the  number is bigger than 4 bytes), while logic always takes the same amount of time. When would the second implementation work faster than the first? Also, I understand that the second one doesn't work on expressions, but only on variables and that for the second one it's possible to put any any data-type, not just integral ones and that first requires integral types(`double` and `float` included).

Edit: I've found an error in the first code(I'm suprised that nobody pointed this out): instead of `>`, there should have been a `>=`.

Comment: Please don't write code like that. Let the compiler worry about such things. It will more than likely be able to generate the best and most optimal code for your use-case.

Comment: Please watch [What has my compiler done for me lately?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4) to get an idea of just a fraction of the optimizations compilers will do.

Comment: Your first define is not valid as it will overflow.

Comment: @Fe2O3 The XOR operation is not even necessary. You can write: `(((a) >= 0) == ((b) >= 0))`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, you're right, would have that been optimized to something like my second code(referring to logic)?

Comment: @markoj Have a look at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Wqx4eocfb) to see how your code gets optimized by different compilers. Note that the case for integers is simple, it XORs the two values and then extracts the sign bit of the result. For floats it gets more complex, but consider that it also has to deal with [NaNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). You can change `-O2` to `-Ofast` to see it can shave off a few instructions by ignoring the possibility of NaNs.

Comment: Thanks, I know about Compiler Explorer, I wanted to ask because I heard that with `==` and `!=`, instead of subtracting and based on the `ZF`(zero flag) branching, use `xor` instead to run faster.

Comment: @markoj Indeed, *if* you have a flag that is set then you can use that to branch. That's what the compiler [will do](https://godbolt.org/z/jcMzefjMK) for `int`. For floating point numbers it's again more difficult because of NaNs. If you don't care about correctness, you can [reinterpret them as integers](https://godbolt.org/z/xonxG4cdd) and then do the integer comparison.

Comment: @G.Sliepen By violating strict aliasing like that, you risk getting results such as a value not having the same sign as itself.  Not caring about correctness extends to the results, too.

Comment: Don't understand the question. For native types (integers, float, doubles) most architecture provide a dedicated comparison instruction or an optimized software library. Why do yiou want to reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: @G.Sliepen: The other sticking point is that `-0.0 >= 0` is true in IEEE floating point.  So compilers can't optimize to `xorps` / `movmskps`/`pd` even with `-ffast-math`.  `-ffast-math` doesn't necessarily *preserve* signed zero in its optimizations, but I think compilers still try to treat it correctly when it happens.  If you don't mind treating negative zero as negative (appropriate for a multiply/divide result that could have underflowed), then yeah type-pun is a good plan.  clang even does optimize it to `xorps` / `movmsk` / `and eax,1`: https://godbolt.org/z/q7hcPnhMa

Comment: Offsetting `char*` to access a single byte of an object is likely to compile to worse asm than just using shifts!  `(a^b) >> (sizeof(a)*CHAR_BIT - 1)` is also more readable.

Comment: C doesn't have an overloaded `*` operator for arbitrary bigint types, and 64-bit multiply is still constant time even on 32-bit machines (although it will take 3 multiplies: low x low and a cross product).  But it can overflow which is UB for signed, and truncating for unsigned.  It takes 4 multiplies to implement 128x128 => 128-bit multiplication on x86-64, but only one for 64x64 => 128-bit (`a * (__int128)b`), and hopefully a compiler would be smart enough to see what's going on.  Since you mention complexity classes, what kind of bigint or struct data types do you care about supporting?

Comment: Also one question is whether you want to optimize the code for low-latency or throughput. On mainstream x86-64 processors, a 64-bit integer multiplication takes 3 cycles of latency and 1 cycle of throughput. The comparison takes 1 cycle for both. This is not a lot, especially if the operation is done using SIMD instructions. So is there really a bottleneck on this? Isn't that a *premature optimization*?

Comment: @PeterCordes: `(a^b) >> (sizeof(a)*CHAR_BIT - 1)` has implementation defined behavior if `a` and `b` have a different sign. Furthermore, this expression does not work for a macro where `a` and `b` should be parenthesized and `sizeof(a)` could differ from `sizeof(b)`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Right, but all sane implementations do a logical or arithmetic right shift so it's either 0 or non-zero.  Even if they have the same type, ISO C allows padding bits.  `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT` assumes they're all value bits.  (Of course that's not a real problem in modern implementations.)  I just thought of `a^b >= 0` for myself before glancing down at your answer; sign-extension will do the trick.  And it encourages the compiler to do `xor` / `js` if you're branching on it.  Of course, if the expression has an unsigned type, you're screwed, so it'd be nice to have C++ std::make_signed

Comment: @chqrlie: I think the [x86] tag is appropriate for a [micro-optimization] question.  If you have one primary ISA that you care about, that makes the question more specific.  It happens that the best answer for x86 is also the best answer for most/all other ISAs, but the comments about stuff like `xorps` / `movmskps` for float are specific to x86.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I agree, but there is nothing specific to the intel architecture in this question and the OP seems to use the `INTEL_REVERSED` identifier to name little endian byte order, which is not intel specific, and predates the company itself.  Promoting architecture specific solutions that have no clear advantage leads to useless micro-optimisation tricks such as the macro posted.

Comment: @chqrlie: Fair point about using macros to attempt portability.  But as for promoting bad solutions, an answer that did that would be bad, and deserve a downvote, unless there was actually something to gain on some specific compiler for some ISA.  Here, there is relevant x86 stuff to talk about, like encouraging compilers other than clang to use `xorps` to XOR floats instead of copying two FP bit-patterns to integer registers for integer xor.  Your answer could be improved by showing how it compiles for x86, to check that `signbit()` inlines as we hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplication method is as slow as you might expect, but it is risky: it has undefined behavior if there is an overflow, which is not unlikely for a multiplication, eg: `same_sign(-50000, -50000)`.

Instead of the complicated, system specific macro posted, you can use this simple method:

```
static inline int same_sign(int a, int b) { return (a ^ b) >= 0; }
```

If you really want a macro to handle integer types `int`, `long` and `long long` with a single expression, use this:

```
#define same_sign(a, b) (((a) ^ (b)) >= 0)
```

The above solutions work for two's complement representation of signed integers. Other representations will have false positives, but you are unlikely to encounter such oddities and support for these will be removed from the next version of the C Standard.

For floating point values, you should use this instead:

```
#include <math.h>
#define same_sign(a, b) (signbit(a) == signbit(b))
```

Note that you can write a macro that will work for all non complex number types and should compile to efficient code:

```
#define same_sign(a, b) (((a) < 0) == ((b) < 0))
```

Comment: As well as having signed-overflow UB on overflow, the multiply method is broken in practice even if you use `gcc -fwrapv` to make it well-defined as truncating the 2's complement bit-pattern.  You *could* use `a * (int64_t)b` for 32-bit or narrower types, and `a * (__int128)b` for 64-bit types on 64-bit systems with GNU C, but you don't want it to compile to an actual widening-multiply instruction like x86 `imul` or RISC-V `mulh` high-half multiply.

Comment: By far the best asm implementation is `xor` the whole value (assuming it fits in one register) and then testing the high bit like you're doing, e.g. x86 sets SF based on the MSB of an XOR result, so `js` or `jns`.  If you want a `bool` result, a good compiler is capable of using a right-shift.  But if you're branching, branching directly on the MSB with xor/branch is possible on most ISAs.  (Including RISC-V and MIPS which don't have FLAGS; they have branches like `blt  x1, x0, target`  or `bltz $t0, target`.)  So +1, that's what this does.

Comment: Maybe `~((a^0)^(b^0))`?

Comment: @markoj: `a^0` is a no-op.

Comment: You're right, @chqrlie, `~(a^b)` is the same thing.

Comment: @markoj: and `~(a^b)` is non zero if `a` and `b` have any bit in common, not just the sign bit.

Comment: Thanks, @chqrlie. Sorry, I forgot what the question is about.